# Receiving "E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)" when performing the command: "sudo apt upgrade" on Kali Linux

Tags: linux, debian, upgrade, kernel, apt

When I run `sudo apt upgrade` or other related commands, I receive an error `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`. The full command being executed can be shown below:

```
sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up linux-headers-6.3.0-kali1-amd64 (6.3.7-1kali1) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.3.0-kali1-amd64.
The kernel is be built without module signing facility, modules won't be signed

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
'make' -j4 KVER=6.3.0-kali1-amd64 KSRC=/lib/modules/6.3.0-kali1-amd64/build.............(bad exit status: 2)
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.3.0-kali1-amd64 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.3.0-kali1-amd64/x86_64 succeeded for realtek-rtl8814au realtek-rtl88xxau
dkms autoinstall on 6.3.0-kali1-amd64/x86_64 failed for 8812au(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
dkms: autoinstall for kernel: 6.3.0-kali1-amd64 failed!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
Failed to process /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-headers-6.3.0-kali1-amd64.postinst line 11.
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.3.0-kali1-amd64 (--configure):
 installed linux-headers-6.3.0-kali1-amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up linux-image-6.3.0-kali1-amd64 (6.3.7-1kali1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.3.0-kali1-amd64.
The kernel is be built without module signing facility, modules won't be signed

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
'make' -j4 KVER=6.3.0-kali1-amd64 KSRC=/lib/modules/6.3.0-kali1-amd64/build...............(bad exit status: 2)
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.3.0-kali1-amd64 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.3.0-kali1-amd64/x86_64 succeeded for realtek-rtl8814au realtek-rtl88xxau
dkms autoinstall on 6.3.0-kali1-amd64/x86_64 failed for 8812au(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
dkms: autoinstall for kernel: 6.3.0-kali1-amd64 failed!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.3.0-kali1-amd64 (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.3.0-kali1-amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-amd64:
 linux-image-amd64 depends on linux-image-6.3.0-kali1-amd64 (= 6.3.7-1kali1); however:
  Package linux-image-6.3.0-kali1-amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-6.3.0-kali1-amd64
 linux-image-6.3.0-kali1-amd64
 linux-image-amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Appreciate any assistance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem too, this helped me:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-headers-6.3.0-kali1-amd64.*

sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-6.3.0-kali1-amd64.*

sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-amd64.*

sudo dpkg --configure -a

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade
```